# Swift for Windows 10 print() command not printing

Tags: swift, stdout

I'm trying out [the swift getting started guide](https://swift.org/getting-started/) on Windows 10 and have managed to install and get swift up and running. I've even managed to get most of the code from the REPL guide to run according to the guide. However, when I try to `print()` stuff, nothing happens. Also, if I try to follow the "tab completion" example (`"Hi!".re⇥`), nothing happens either.

I guess this could be something about swift not connecting correctly to stdout, but I'm not sure how to fix this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

This is the output from `swift --version`:

```
compnerd.org Swift version 5.3.1 (swift-5.3.1-RELEASE)
Target: x86_64-unknown-windows-msvc
```